# Запись массива в cookies

Tags: php, cookie

Здравствуйте. 
Проблема такая: пытаюсь записать массив в cookies при помощи setcookie. Делаю так, как и написано во всех мануалах:

```
setcookie ("cookie[three]", "cookiethree");
setcookie ("cookie[two]", "cookietwo");
setcookie ("cookie[one]", "cookieone");
```

Получается, работает, всё нормально. Но таким способом создаётся сразу же три файла cookies - cookie[one], cookie[two], cookie[three], а я хотел, чтобы файл был только один!

Скорее всего, я спрашиваю какую-то очевидную для всех вещь, так как в программировании не очень хорош, но, может, кто-нибудь подскажет, как сделать так, чтобы массив записывался в один файл cookies, а не так, чтобы для каждого элемента создавался новый файл.
Заранее спасибо всем за внимание!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$cook_val = array('cook_one' => 'one', 'cook_two' => 'two', 'cook_three' => 'three');

setcookie('some_cookie_name', serialize($cook_val));

$get_cook = unserialize($_COOKIE['some_cookie_name']);

echo $get_cook['cook_one'];
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.